# Is there a way to configure a "Topic exchange" to send the non routed messages to a queue?

Tags: message-queue, rabbitmq

With the default behaviour when a message is not routed the message is lost.

Comment: I think you did not mean to put the exchange tag on this question.  That is for MS Exchange email server.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a queue that receives all messages by using the # for the routing key in the binding.  Then create a process that handles all the non routed messages.  The process will have to connect to the queue and receive all messages and somehow know whether they have been routed or not.  What you will need to do is call the management plugin cli to return all the bindings for an exchange.  Parse that result to get you this list of the bindings for the exchange and ignore any incoming message which matches the bindings.  Then you can just process the ones that never got routed in the first place.  You could even read them back to another queue for a worker process to consume.
have a look at [this](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html) for information on the management plugin cli.
If you prefer to use the rabbitmqctl you could use

```
sudo rabbitmqclt report
```

to get a report that would need to be parsed to get all the bindings.  See [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html)